# PHP Split over multiple lines does not work

Tags: php, regex, file, line, new-operator

I have a regex given in an xml like

```
<sectiondelimiter><![CDATA[/--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/]]></sectiondelimiter>
```

which I read out with SimpleXML

```
$data = preg_split($file->sectiondelimiter, $my_file, null, 1 );
```

If I read in a file with file_get_contents, here is an extract, it does not split and returns an array of size 1.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ClassicCLI ENABLED:  Yes

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- start:  no interval:  60 address: serverkey: keyvalue:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********************************************************************************

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What does happen? If I use [a regex tool](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/), it splits nice as expected.

**Edit:** Here's the raw regex:

```
/--------------------------------------------------------------------------------.\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
/-{80}\s+\*{80}/
```

This allows any kind of whitespace between the line of `-`s and the line of `*`s, no matter how many characters are used to represent a line break.